# Kotlin Poet empty constructor generation - inheritance

Tags: java, constructor, kotlin, kotlinpoet

I'm trying to print a call to superclass' constructor using KotlinPoet. My current (not compiling) output is:

```
open class NameOfASubclass : NameOfSuperclass {
}
```

In order to make my code compile I need to (somehow) either print

```
open class NameOfASubclass : NameOfSuperclass() {
}
```

or

```
open class NameOfASubclass : NameOfSuperclass {
constructor()
}
```

I cannot achieve it using KotlinPoet. Any ideas?

Comment: Can you post your Poet generation code?

Comment: sure

`PACKAGE_NAME = resolvePackageName(classModel)
        val className = resolveDataModelClassName(classModel.className)
        val builder = KotlinFile.builder(PACKAGE_NAME, className)
        builder.addType(TypeSpec.classBuilder(className).addModifiers(KModifier.OPEN).primaryConstructor(FunSpec.constructorBuilder().build())
                .superclass(resolveSuperClass(classModel)).build())`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

indeed in Kotlin Poet the problem is solved in v.0.4.0

Answer (score 3):

This is a bug. [Here's](https://github.com/square/kotlinpoet/issues/120) the issue for it and [here](https://github.com/square/kotlinpoet/commit/aa3cd39c237cc99885972656eb53e2843c2202a0) is the commit that fixes it.

There hasn't been a new release since this commit (16 of June), the last stable version is `0.3.0` (11th of June). Hopefully a new release is coming soon - there's been lots of work done since the previous one.